# Android Room With Custom Type Converter Live Data Triggers continuously

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

After add Type Converter Live Data Triggers continuously

This is My JobImages Entity

```
@Entity
@TypeConverters({AddOnConverter.class})
public class JobImagesTable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id; 

    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_marked_image")
    String jobMarkedImage;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "complexity_id")
    int complexityId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "addons_data")
    ArrayList<AddonService> addOnsData = new ArrayList<>();


    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    int status;    

}
```

This my DAO

```
@Dao
public interface JobImagesDao {   


    @Query("SELECT * FROM JobImagesTable WHERE job_id=:job_id AND is_delete = 0")
    LiveData<List<JobImagesTable>> getImagesForView(int job_id);

}
```

AddOnService Class

```
public class AddonService implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("AddonID")
    @Expose
    private int addonID;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("ExtraCredits")
    @Expose
    private double extraCredits;

    @SerializedName("isSelected")
    @Expose
    private boolean isSelected;

    public AddonService() {
    }
}
```

Converter Class

```
public class AddOnConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<AddonService> fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<AddonService>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<AddonService> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;
    }
}
```

This Database class

```
@Database(entities = {JobImagesTable.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract JobImagesDao getOriginImagesDao();
}
```

I am not getting any compile time errors, But while go the screen Livedata triggers continuously after added Type converter any wrong ?

Comment: Have you added TypeConverters for `AddonService` ? and can you post model for the `AddonService`.
It also need to have its own TypeConverter as its not identified directly by Room

Comment: @adityakamble49 Check now

Comment: You can try with `@Embedded` annotation by embedding the nested object property instead of converting into json to see if the problem still persist